# Making Grunt automatically remove files that are deleted

Tags: html, gruntjs, pug

I use Grunt to automate converting my jade files. For that I use this script:

```
    jade: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                client: false,
                pretty: true
            },
            files: [{
                cwd: "_/components/jade",
                src: "**/*.jade",
                dest: "_/html",
                expand: true,
                ext: ".html"
        }]
        }
    }
```

I also have this watch script running:

```
    watch: {
        jade: {
            files: ['_/components/jade/**/*.jade'],
            tasks: ['jade']
        }
    }
```

This works fine. However, when I delete a jade file, the html file remains. Is there a way to make grunt delete the corresponding html files when I delete a jade file?

Comment: This plugin should solve your troubles https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-clean

Comment: @Avalanche I tried it out, but that just deleted all the files in every folder. Very poor documentation, hard to see if it can be used for my purposes.

Comment: You can just explicitly state the 'index.html' file as the target for grunt-contrib-clean.

Comment: @PeteTNT That does not solve my problem. I want grunt to delete the html equivalent files of the jade files I delete, how would having the 'index.html' file as target do that?

Comment: @ArashSaidi - Sorry, I was in a hurry: see my answer for complete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, if you delete `foo.jade` you also want to delete `foo.html` correct? Here's an complete example using `grunt-contrib-clean` and `grunt-contrib-watch`:

You start by watching all the files with `.jade` extension with `grunt watch`. When a watched file is modified in some way, a `watch` event is emitted. If the event is `deleted`, we take the file path, change the extension to `.html`, set it as the `src` value of the `clean:jade` task and run the task.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        clean: {
            jade: {
                src: null
            }
        },
        watch: {
            jade: {
                files: ['*.jade'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-clean");

    grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
        if (action === "deleted") {
            var file = filepath.slice(0, -5) + ".html";
            grunt.config.set('clean.jade.src', [file]);
            grunt.task.run("clean:jade");
        }
    });
};
```

For more information, see [Using the watch event @ grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#using-the-watch-event). Note that `spawn` option must be `false`

> If you need to dynamically modify your config, the spawn option must be disabled to keep the watch running under the same context.

Answer (score 0):

You need grunt-contrib-clean. But this code clear all files of same type and make grunt slowly and require a specific config for every task. So often just use clean single time when grunt start:

```
module.exports = function (grunt){

    grunt.initConfig({

        pckg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        clean: { // Grun-contrib-clean tasks
            jade: ["dist/*.html"],
            all: ["dist"]
        },

        jade: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'src/templates',
                    src: ['**/*.jade'],
                    dest: 'dist',
                    filter: 'isFile',
                    ext: '.html'
                }]
            }
        },

        watch: {
            jade: {
                files: ['src/templates/**/*.jade'],
                tasks: ['clean:jade','jade']
            },

        }


    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean:all', 'jade', 'watch']);

};
```